# CakePhp: Prevent rendering element on certain view

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I want an element to render on all pages so I called it in default.ctp. I want to prevent it from appearing on two or three specific page.

I googled and found a solution, which is trying to do exactly what I want to do:

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/saidbakr/2012/04/20/prevent_render_layout_elements_with_the_render_of_some_views

In this solution, the name and path of element is extracted by placing following code in the element:

```
<?php
$e = explode('views/elements/',__FILE__);
$e[1] = str_replace('.ctp', '', $e[1]);
if (isset($this->preventElement) && $e[1] == $this->preventElement[$e[1]]) return false;
?>
```

And the view in which you don't want to rendre that element, this line of code is placed:

```
<?php $this->preventElement['someElement'] = 'someElement';?>
```

Here view object `preventElement` is used, but when tested it I got message `preventElementHelper could not be found.`

I couldn't find any reference to `prventElement`  in cakePhp documentation.

Comment: I am unsure exactly the need for this but have you tried to just hide the element using CSS?  It could be a temporary solution.  Your alternative is to create and reference a different layout which does not include the element.   You can define that for each one of your functions in your controller, if you so decide to change the layout for that function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to render an element, don't you use code something like this?:

`echo $this->element('foobar');`

To render it, why don't you put it inside an if statement, like this:

```
if(!isset($noDisplay)) {
    echo $this->element('foobar');
}
```

In this example, set the variable $noDisplay in the controller, which should make the `if` false and not render.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to just check the controller and action in the request object, and determine if the element should be shown then.

```
<?php
// app/View/Element/your_element_name.ctp

$controller = $this->request->params['controller'];
$action = $this->request->params['action'];

if (($controller == 'foo' && $action == 'bar') || ($controller == 'baz' && $action == 'bob')) {
    continue;
}
```

It’s inelegant, but will do the job.